# Is there a way to reference the opposite corner of a square made with getContext("2d")?

Tags: javascript

In vanilla javascript, if I made two squares, one square with movement like:

```
const context = document.getElementById("canvasmulti").getContext("2d");

canvasmulti.width  = window.innerWidth;
canvasmulti.height = window.innerHeight;

//CHARACTER:
const square = {
    height: 75,
    jumping: true,
    width: 75,
    x: canvasmulti.width - 75,
    xVelocity: 0,
    y: canvasmulti.height / 2,
    yVelocity: 0,
    jumpHeight: 30
  };

  const square2 = {
    height: 75,
    jumping: true,
    width: 75,
    x: 500,
    xVelocity: 0,
    y: canvasmulti.height - 75,
    yVelocity: 0,
    jumpHeight: 30
  };

//MOVEMENT:
const controller = {
    left: false,
    right: false,
    up: false,
    keyListener: function (event) {
      let key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37: // left arrow
          controller.left = key_state;
          break;
        case 38: // up arrow
          controller.up = key_state;
          break;
        case 39: // right arrow
          controller.right = key_state;
          break;
      }
    }
  };

  const loop = function () {

    //controller one
    if (controller.up && square.jumping == false) {
      square.yVelocity -=square.jumpHeight;
      square.jumping = true;}
    if (controller.left) {
      square.xVelocity -= 0.5;}
    if (controller.right) {
      square.xVelocity += 0.5;}
  
      //controller one
    square.yVelocity += 1.5;// gravity
    square.x += square.xVelocity;
    square.y += square.yVelocity;
    square.xVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
    square.yVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
  
    // if square1 is falling below floor line
    if (square.y > canvasmulti.height - 75) {
      square.jumping = false;
      square.y = canvasmulti.height - 75;
      square.yVelocity = 0;
    }
  
    // Creates and fills square1 for each frame
    context.fillStyle = "#8DAA9D"; // hex for cube color
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
    context.fill();

 //creates and full square2 for each frame
context.fillStyle = "#781818"; // hex for cube color
    context.beginPath();
    context.rect(square2.x, square2.y, square2.width, square2.height);
    context.fill();

    if (square.x <= square2.x + square2.width &&
        square.x >= square2.x + square2.width - square2.width && square.y >= square2.y &&
        square.y <= square2.y + square2.height)
        {square.x = square2.x + square2.width; // set it to a position where they don't overlap
         square.xVelocity = 0;}; // left square1 touching right square2

    if (square.x + square.width >= square2.x && square.x + square.width <= square2.x + square2.width && 
        square.y >= square2.y && square.y <= square2.y + square2.height ||
        square.x + square.width >= square2.x && square.x + square.width <= square2.x + square2.width &&
        square.y + square.height >= square2.y && square.y + square.height >= square2.y + square2.height)
        {square.x = square2.x - square.width;
         square.xVelocity = 0;}; // right square1 touching left square2

    if (square.x <= square2.x + square2.width - 0.1 &&
        square.x >= square2.x && square.y + square.height >= square2.y)
        { 
         square.y =  square2.y - square.height; 
         square.yVelocity = 0;}; // bottom left square1 touching top square2

     if (square.x + square.width <= square2.x + square2.width &&
         square.x + square.width >= square2.x + 0.1 && square.y + square.height >= square2.y)
        {square.y = square2.y - square.height;
         square.yVelocity = 0;}; // bottom right square1 touching top square2
    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  };

  //square1
  window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
  window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Since the starting co-ordinate of the square is in the top left, if I wanted to make an if statement saying if the opposite corner was past a point (say square2.x), but also over a point(say square2.y), how would I do that?? You can't add or multiply the co-ordinates, because that would just make one of the co-ordinates larger rather than combining them both.

Comment: Can someone make it so  you can test code here???

Comment: I tried to do it with // right square1 touching left square2 , but idk, I'm stumped

Comment: Community help for [creating a code snippet in your post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/5217142) is available on Meta. More general  [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is available on the help center.

Comment: To get rid of the JavaScript error, set the `y` property of `square2` using "`y: canvasmulti.height - 75,`" . The errror occurs because `square2` has not been set to the object being defined yet.

Comment: @traktor Done :)